# Python ssl/https requests.get call fails

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, https, openssl

I have the following snippet of python (2.7.14) which is throwing an exception on the requests.get call.  This is running on a FreeBSD server, with an apache front end and all http traffic being redirected to https. Note that I am not overly familiar with python, nor this code.  Also the following works fine when running locally on my PC and without https/ssl.

```
urlstr = getApipath()  + 'getData/' + id_data
logging.debug("URL used: %s", urlstr)
try:
   resp = requests.get(urlstr)
except Exception as e:
   logging.exception("caught exception str: " + str(e))
```

The urlstr is an api call and is using https.  The same api call using curl on the same host's command line returns the expected and valid json.

```
curl https://my.domain.com/is/api/getData/D_01
```

The following is the log output including stacktrace when running this (obviously not using real url). Looks like an ssl issue, but the error message string being empty doesn't help.  Any help on what the issue could be greatly appreciated.

```
2018-03-28 10:37:51,530 URL used: https://my.domain.org/is/api/getData/D_01
2018-03-28 10:37:51,531 Starting new HTTPS connection (1): my.domain.org
2018-03-28 10:37:51,540 caught excpetion str: []
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/engines/controller/get_data.py", line 25, in getTemplate
    resp = requests.get(urlstr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 346, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 850, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 314, in connect
    cert_reqs=resolve_cert_reqs(self.cert_reqs),
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 254, in create_urllib3_context
    context = SSLContext(ssl_version or ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 379, in __init__
    self._ctx = OpenSSL.SSL.Context(self.protocol)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 724, in __init__
    _openssl_assert(res == 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 67, in openssl_assert
    exception_from_error_queue(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
    raise exception_type(errors)
Error: []
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An upgrade to the python cryptography module fixed the issue.  The installed version was 2.1.4.  Turns out there was a newer version available - 2.2.2 which after installing cleared the problem.